Making a RAM item the same size as a ROM entry in wla-dx
I'm writing a SNES program using wla-dx (wla-65816 specifically), and I'm including some binary data in the ROM:
data: .INCBIN "datafile.bin"

I can get the size of this data using _sizeof_data, which can be used in e.g. macro arguments. However, I'm having trouble reserving a region of RAM with the same size as this. Perhaps this is because of the clunky way I've fond to reserve longer ram sections. For a known-in-advance size, I currently do something like:
; This struct is used as a workaround for me not finding a way
; to indicate how big a ram section should be
.STRUCT array
  dummy: db
.ENDST

.RAMSECTION "Work" SLOT 1 ORG $100 SEMIFREE
   work_data instanceof array size $1000
.ENDS

This works, but it appears a variable size is not accepted for the size argument here. Replacing $1000 with _sizeof_data, I get DIRECTIVE_ERROR: Unexpected symbol "_sizeof_data" in .RAMSECTION.
What is the right way to do this? I could just hardcode a size, but I don't think what I'm doing here should be unusual. There's probably a better way to do this that I'm not seeing.

Looks like .DSB _sizeof_data, 0 would reserve the right-sized block of RAM.

@jasonharper .dsb can't be used in RAM sections, since .dsb defines bytes with specific values, and the compiler can't affect what will end up in RAM. But the closely related .ds does work, when coupled with a better way of getting the size. See the answer I posted almost at the same time as your comment. Thanks for looking at this though, your comment would have been a big lead if I didn't happen to find the answer just before.

I found it after spending some more time trawling through the manual.
Firstly, the size hack with the struct can be avoided by using ds [size]. For the fixed-size example above, that would be
.RAMSECTION "Work" SLOT 1 ORG $100 SEMIFREE
   work_data ds $1000
.ENDS

Secondly, use FSIZE with .INCBIN to get the size. The result can be used with ds. Perhaps the _sizeof_ stuff never worked - at least it doesn't work with ds. So one would do: data: .INCBIN "datafile.bin" FSIZE data_size, and then work_data ds data_size.
